# Wordpress log in to dashboard redirection back and forth

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm new in wordpress code & php programming and I did this :

I customised a "**log in / Register**" Page (Page ID 446) to improve the classical woocommerce log in page via "Forminator" plugin.
When the user is logged in, you can set de behavior via the plugin directly .

The issue is when I reload the "log in /register" page, the plugin shows a massage like " You are already connected" and I want to set a function that can redirect to the classic dashboard page (ID 1671) when the user is logged in.

I found this peace of code :

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && is_page(446)) {
        wp_redirect('https://my-web-site.com/woo-dashboard/');
        exit;
       } 
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

The redirection works fine but when I try to log out, it doesn't work . I can see the page refreshing but the session never logs out

I also tried this code but it doesn't work too :

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page(1671)) {
        wp_redirect('https://my-web-site.com/register/');
        exit;
       } if (is_user_logged_in() && is_page(446)) {
        wp_redirect('https://my-web-site.com/woo-dashboard/');
       }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

Do you have any idea where the issue is coming from ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution but I don't understand why it works ...

here is the code :

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page(1671) ) {
        wp_redirect('https://my-web-site.com/register/');
        
    } elseif (is_user_logged_in() && is_page(446)) {
        wp_redirect('https://my-web-site.com/woo-dashboard/');
        
    }
        
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

When I put the endif , it tells me that there is an syntax error and I don't understand why...